# How do figure out which column is different in a row?

Tags: excel

I am having a hard time with this issue. I need to figure out which column is different for a row. Is there any excel tool that I can use that can highlight which column is not accurate for a row? Please look at these 2 attachments. There are 2 rows that have a different column on sheet 2 than sheet 1 (row 3 and row 7).

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Use 'Excel Compare' that comes with Office

Comment: Sorry, I am new to excel so I don't know what you exactly mean by that, do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting and a comparison formula between sheets.
See e.g. https://trumpexcel.com/compare-two-columns/
AND
https://trumpexcel.com/compare-two-excel-sheets/

Go to Sheet1 cell F2 and add the following `=A2<>Sheet2!A2`
Then you drag towards the right.

It will show `True` when the cell matches, and `False` when it does not match.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. I have actually watched those 2 videos but it doesn't apply in my case. I want to see which values in row matches and highlight the ones that don't and it has to be without order. I cannot figure that out even after watching those videos. I already used a formula to identify which rows don't match but I need excel tell me due to which column they don't match.

Comment: @Hellokitty0987  You need to do it based on ID number? Do you want to compare rows with the same ID number?

Comment: I want to base it on every column in this case. If we look at Row 3 on both sheets, we can see there's a difference in date. I want excel to highlight that for me. In this case we can eyeball it but I have 1 million rows and I was able to figure out which rows were different but I need to know how many columns matched for one row and which ones didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula:
Use `IF(A2=Sheet2!A2,"OK","KO")` into cell (new sheet or new column) in this example from `G2` to `K8`.

After you can use conditional formatting to color the cells with KO.
This is an example

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Result into Sheet1 from column G2 to K8**
you can use the formula into another sheet. In this example i used the formula into cells G2 to K8. `IF(A2=Sheet2!A2,"OK","KO")`

[image]

> UPDATE ANSWER AFTER YOUR ANSWER

Your situation is not easy and the following code solve a part of your needs.
(RUN THE CODE INTO SHEET1.

1.This code works well when the sheet1 has a number of rows > sheet2 and the row are more or less in order.

2.The code check the KO row in order. For example if you have into sheet2 1262 Matt Cavvy business development 05-May-18 into last row(sheet2), the code doesn't find the 1262 Matt Cavvy business analyst 05-May-18(sheet1). In this case you get KO row.

```
Sub check()

Dim lastRowSheet1, lastRowSheet2 As Integer ' Long
Dim i, j As Integer ' Long

'count the row numebrs into sheet1
lastRowSheet1 = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox lastRow
With Sheets("Sheet2")

    'count the row numbers into sheet2
    lastRowSheet2 = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'first check. I control if there are the same row present into sheet1 into sheet2 (not in order)
    For i = 2 To lastRowSheet1
        For j = 2 To lastRowSheet2
        
            'check the row from sheet1 if there is present into sheet2 and it is ok froeach cell
            If (Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(j, 1)) Then
            
                If (Cells(i, 2) = .Cells(j, 2) And Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(j, 4) And Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(j, 5)) Then
                
                    Cells(i, 6) = "OK"
                    .Cells(j, 6) = "OK"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Cells(i, 6) = "KO"
                    .Cells(i, 6) = "KO"
                End If
            End If
    
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'second check. I check the KO row from sheet1 into sheet2(in order)
    For i = 2 To lastRowSheet1
        For j = 2 To lastRowSheet2
        
            'check the row from sheet1 if there is present into sheet2 and it is ok froeach cell
            If (Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 6) = "KO" And .Cells(j, 6) = "KO") Then
            
                Cells(i, 6) = "OK" 'check the row and put ok into column 6 (F)
                If (Cells(i, 2) = .Cells(j, 2)) Then
                    
                    Cells(i, 7) = "OK"
                    If (Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(j, 3)) Then
                    
                        Cells(i, 9) = "OK"
                        If (Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(j, 4)) Then
                    
                            Cells(i, 10) = "OK"
                            If (Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(j, 5)) Then
                    
                                Cells(i, 11) = "OK"
                                            
                            Else
                                Cells(i, 11) = "KO"
                                Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' red color cell
                                Exit For
                            End If
                    
                        Else
                            Cells(i, 10) = "KO"
                            Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' red color cell
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    
                    Else
                        Cells(i, 9) = "KO"
                        Cells(i, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' red color cell
                        Exit For
                    End If
                
                Else
                    Cells(i, 8) = "KO"
                    Cells(i, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' red color cell
                    Exit For
                End If
            'Else
            '    i = i + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End With
End Sub
```

The following the result after the code:

**Sheet1:**

In column F there are the OK and KO results. You get OK when the rows are the same or it is good but with column not good. You get the KO when the row into sheet1 there is not into sheet2 and the row into sheet1 there is intosheet2 but not in order.

[image]

Into sheet2 the code use the column F to write ok and ko result.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please show me your full formula? Is this formula based on a specific row tho? Because what if that (02-Jun-17) was in the column K but somewhere at the bottom, then it wouldn't highlight it?

Comment: in this example there is a cell-by-cell match. That is, the rows of sheet one must be in the same order as the rows of sheet 2. Can you order the two sheets from Id number?

Comment: I don't think mine would be in order because in one sheet I could have 3 rows with the same ID number and in the other one, I could have 4 so this formula won't work :(

Comment: I could use one but I don't know how to code